# unexpected end of file in PHP, but why

Tags: php

I wrote the following code and got an unexpexted end of file errror. Do you see why?
The error refers to my last line of code.
I read the other pages concerning this error on stackoverflow and other forums, followed their instructions but it still does not work.

```
<?php 
session_start();
$pdo = new PDO(...);
if(isset($_GET['register'])) {
$error = false;
$email = $_POST['email'];
$passwort = $_POST['passwort'];
$passwort2 = $_POST['passwort2'];
$firstName = $_POST['firstName'];
$lastName = $_POST['lastName'];
$username = $_POST['username'];

if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    echo 'Bitte eine gültige E-Mail-Adresse eingeben<br />';
    $error = true;
}   
if(strlen($passwort) == 0) {
    echo 'Bitte ein Passwort angeben<br />';
    $error = true;
}
if(strlen($firstName) == 0) {
    echo 'Bitte ein Passwort angeben<br />';
    $error = true;
}
if(strlen($lastName) == 0) {
    echo 'Bitte ein Passwort angeben<br />';
    $error = true;
}
if($passwort != $passwort2) {
    echo 'Die Passwörter müssen übereinstimmen<br />';
    $error = true;
}
if(strlen($username) == 0) {
    echo 'Please enter a username<br />';
    $error = true;

//Überprüfe, dass die E-Mail-Adresse noch nicht registriert wurde
if(!$error) { 
    $statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = :email");
    $result = $statement->execute(array(':email' => $email));
    $mail = $statement->fetch();

    if($mail !== false) {
        echo 'Diese E-Mail-Adresse ist bereits vergeben<br />';
        $error = true;
    }   
}

if(!$error) { 
    $statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = :username");
    $result = $statement->execute(array(':username' => $username));
    $user = $statement->fetch();

    if($user !== false) {
        echo 'Diese E-Mail-Adresse ist bereits vergeben<br />';
        $error = true;
    }   
}

//Keine Fehler, wir können den Nutzer registrieren
if(!$error) {   
    $passwort_hash = password_hash($passwort, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

    $statement = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO users (email, passwort) VALUES (:email, :passwort)");
    $result = $statement->execute(array('email' => $email, 'passwort' => $passwort_hash));

    if($result) {
        $link = '<a href="$_SESSION["lastPage"]">Login</a>';
        $_SESSION["loggedIn"] = true;
        die("The registration was successful.<br />$link");
    } else {
        echo 'There was a mistake. Please try again!<br />';
    }
} 
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head>
<title>Sign in</title>  
</head> 
<body>
<form action="?register=1" method="post">
Firstname:<br />
<input type="text" size="40" maxlength="250" name="firstName"><br />

Lastname:<br />
 <input type="text" size="40" maxlength="250" name="lastName"><br /><br />

username(used to login):<br />
<input type="text" size="40" maxlength="250" name="username"><br /><br />

E-Mail:<br />
<input type="email" size="40" maxlength="250" name="email"><br /><br />


Dein Passwort:<br />
<input type="password" size="40"  maxlength="250" name="passwort"><br />
Passwort wiederholen:<br />
<input type="password" size="40" maxlength="250" name="passwort2"><br /><br />
<input type="submit" value="Sign In">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: one more `}` required

Comment: Also three times `if(!$error) { ` same condition, you are going to get nothing with such type of coding

Comment: Take a look around for a decent development environment. Todays solution can be if amazing help with such issues. I recomment "IntelliJ IDEA" for php development...

Comment: `I recomment "IntelliJ IDEA" `? what is it?